# Version Compatibility with Gradle, Spring and Java Version

Tags: java, spring-boot, gradle

How to check which version of Spring Boot and Java is compatible with Gradle version.
Most of time when I download spring app from spring starter it start throwing while running.
I fix it by changing **gradle-wrapper.properties** file and spring boot version in **build.gralde** file.
Currently I am using

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-7.5-bin.zip
```

with Spring boot version

```
id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.7.3'
java version 17
```

And it is working fine on my current pc, But same conf is not workin on my other pc, there I have installed java 21.

After changing **springboot version to 3 and gradle wrapper version to 8**, application started working.

How do I check which gralde + springboot + java is compatible?