build/lib not generated by gradle build
I am working on the spring-boot project from Magnus Larsson's 2nd edition book with gradle 8.11.
I have a multi project structure and I build the jars by running ./gradlew clean build -x test in the topmost directory. This generates jars for all sub-modules (sub-projects?) in their respective build/lib directories.
The problem is I added a new sub-project authorization-server which uses springboot 2.4.4 whereas rest of the projects use springboot 2.6.7.
Now, when I am running the above command, I don't see any build/lib directory inside the sub-project authorization-server. I have the sub-project included in the top-level settings.gradle file with the line include ':spring-cloud:authorization-server'.
As a result, I don't have any jar created for this sub-project.

Can the different spring boot version be an issue?

I have been stuck with this since quite a long time. I am quite new to gradle - so, I am unsure what I am doing wrong. Please help me in solving the same.
Following is my settings.gradle content inside authorization-server:
rootProject.name = 'authorization-server'

And following is my build.gradle content inside authorization-server:
plugins {
    // Can't upgrade to Spring Boot 2.5.x until fixes for the following issues are released:
    // 1. https://github.com/spring-projects-experimental/spring-authorization-server/issues/305
    // 2. https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-security/issues/9787
    id 'java'
    id 'org.springframework.boot' version '2.4.4'
//    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.1.5'
    id 'io.spring.dependency-management' version '1.0.11.RELEASE'
}

group = 'com.abc.xyz.practice.springcloud'
version = '1.0.0-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = '1.8'

//java {
//    toolchain {
//        languageVersion = JavaLanguageVersion.of(8)
//    }
//}
//
//jar {
//    enabled = false
//}

ext {
    set('springCloudVersion', "2020.0.2")
}

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-actuator'
    implementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-security'
    implementation 'org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-starter-netflix-eureka-client'
    implementation 'org.springframework.security.experimental:spring-security-oauth2-authorization-server:0.1.0'

    testImplementation 'org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test'
}

dependencyManagement {
    imports {
        mavenBom "org.springframework.cloud:spring-cloud-dependencies:${springCloudVersion}"
    }
}

test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
}

Edit:

I can see the rest of the sub-folders like classes, generated etc. inside the build directory of the authorization-server project - only the libs directory is missing.
Also, the command ./gradlew clean build -x test runs successfully
Jars for the remaining sub-projects are being generated, as usual.


Any change if you run ./gradlew -p authorization-server bootJar ?

@RoarS. Wow! That worked!! I can see the jar now! Can you please explain this in the answer so I can upvote the same? Do I have to execute it all the time? If no, then what is the solution?

We'll have to find a more permanent solution, but now we know that target bootJar is working.

@RoarS. Can you please at-least post this as an answer? Or can you please tell what made you suggest the command? (I can debug it further, no issues)

Can you change classpath to mainClass and add this to build.gradle? springBoot { mainClass = "no.mycompany.AuthorizationApplication" }

@RoarS. I am really new to gradle. How and where do I change the classpath? And what is the no.mycompany? Do I need to replace it with something? What is this command exactly?

Change no.mycompany.AuthorizationApplication to package name + classname for the application class inside module authorization-server

Let us continue this discussion in chat.

OP has confirmed that the following command builds the missing JAR-file:
./gradlew -p spring-cloud/authorization-server bootJar

I could not reproduce the issue with a multimodule Spring Boot project on my computer, so the solution was to add
tasks.named("build") {
    dependsOn("bootJar")
}

in order to force execution of target bootJar.

Does the answer in this link help to debug this further: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78158870/version-compatibility-with-gradle-spring-and-java-version ? Could this be the reason?

@Python_user: You can always try to upgrade Gradle wrapper to latest:  ./gradlew wrapper --gradle-version latest. My primary suspect is mixed Spring Boot versions though. BR

Ok... I tried the same command on the author's repo (after cloning it) - this worked and all JARs were generated. But, when I ran ./gradlew -version on the author's repo , i found that the author uses gradle 7.0 ... I am using 8.11.1, which might not be compatible with 2.4.4 . I tried searching, but it seems that this compatibility info is not easily available

@Python_user: I believe there is a third edition of the code here: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Microservices-with-Spring-Boot-and-Spring-Cloud-Third-Edition
If this is the correct repo, that is using Spring Boot 3 and Java 17, which is a much better starting point. BR

Yes yes there is, i know ... I have the 2nd edition book, which I bought last year before this 3rd edition was published ... I started with this book this year only ... My org still uses Java 8 and SB 2.6.7, so I decided to stick with the 2nd edition ... Once I complete this (may be in the next 3 weeks?), I will just skim through the 3rd edition (& also implement it as a separate project, if required) ... The author actually advises to execute his repo, but I decided to try all by myself ...
Thanks a lot! :)
(Btw, this is an excellent book!)

Btw, I am looking into the repo for the 2nd edition: https://github.com/PacktPublishing/Microservices-with-Spring-Boot-and-Spring-Cloud-2E (as I have the 2nd edition book)
